# Object.assign() Issues on Mongoose SubDocument Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So when I use Object.assign, (ex. Object.assign({foo:bar1},{foo:bar2}) on a particular Mongoose Subdocument Schema, the foo:bar2 obj won't overwrite the foo:bar1 obj.

In my app I have an Account Schema with two sub-document schemas, Projects & Properties. It's in the Project sub document schema that I encounter the issue.

Here are my Models:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    name: String,
}, { strict: false })

var PropertySchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    slug: String,
    name: String,
    type: String,
    placeholder: String,
    order: Number
}, { strict: false })

var AccountSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    name: String,
    slug: String,
    email: String,
    properties: [PropertySchema],
    projects: [ProjectSchema],
}, { strict: false })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
```

Here is a snippet of my Middleware(I think that's what it's called, please correct me if I am wrong). This is where I do the Object.assign to overwrite the particular projects' properties. If it helps I can post all the routes.

```
router.route('/accounts/:account_id/projects/:project_id')

  .get(function(req, res) {
    Project.findById(req.params.project_id, function(err, project){
      if (err) 
        res.send(err);
      res.json(project);
    });
  })

  .delete(function(req, res){
    Account.findById(req.params.account_id, function(err,account){
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      account.projects.id(req.params.project_id).remove();

      account.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json({message: 'Project Deleted'});
      });
    })
  })

  .put(function(req, res){
    Account.findById(req.params.account_id, function(err,account){
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      Object.assign(account.projects.id(req.params.project_id), req.body);

      account.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json({message: 'Project Updated'});
      });
    })
  });

// ----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/accounts/:account_id/properties/:property_id')

  .get(function(req, res) {
    Property.findById(req.params.property_id, function(err, property){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json(property);
    });
  })

  .delete(function(req, res){
    Account.findById(req.params.account_id, function(err, account){
      if (err)
        res.send(err);
      account.properties.id(req.params.property_id).remove();
      account.save(function(err){
        if(err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json({ message: 'Successfully Deleted' });
      })
    })
  })

  .put(function(req, res){
    Account.findById(req.params.account_id, function(err, account) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      Object.assign(account.properties.id(req.params.property_id), req.body);

      account.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json({message: 'Property Updated'});
      })
    })
  });
```

So it's the Put Method that is giving me the issue, I can Get, Post, Delete with no issues, but the Put part for Projects is where I encounter this Object.assign issue. Funny thing is that everything works perfectly for the Property Schema Put Method, and it is basically the exact same as the Project one.

If I console.log some of the values in the Project's Put Method I get the following:

```
console.log(account.projects.id(req.params.project_id));
//original value logs { _id: '1486609836741', foo: 'bar' }
console.log(req.body);
//updated value logs { foo: 'barred', _id: '1486609836741' }

console.log(Object.assign(account.projects.id(req.params.project_id), req.body));
//logs the original value { _id: '1486609836741', foo: 'bar' }
```

So when I log the updated and original values they have equal keys, shouldn't the Object.assign work? Is the original Obj more complex then what the console.log displays, and maybe the original and updated don't have equal keys?

I am kinda stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to post more of my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.assign(account.projects.id(req.params.project_id), req.body);
```

Here, you are trying to assign to an object that is result of [MongooseDocumentArray.id](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.htm#types_documentarray_MongooseDocumentArray.id) method call on `account.projects` array. Which will affect just a copy of document which is returned by function, and won't affect the original array of subdocuments.

I am new to Mongoose, but I'll suggest you trying to work with account.projects as with [MongooseArray](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.indexOf):

```
var project = account.projects.id( req.params.project_id ),
    index = account.projects.indexOf( project );

Object.assign( account.projects[ index ], req.body);
```

Comment: I get the same issue of the updated object not assigning to the original account.project.{targetproject}